What's the appropriate way to catch Firestore permission denials in Flutter?
This is not a rules question.  The rules are acting as expected.  However; I can't seem to get my flutter app to respond when a rule is violated.  I've tried wrapping the whole thing in a try/catch, and I've tried onError and catchError but dart just kinda doesn't care about them and locks up when the PermissionDenied comes back.  The snippet below has both catchError AND a try/catch and the thing still won't even give me back a decent debugging trace.

          try {
            FirebaseFirestore.instance
                .collection('profiles')
                .withConverter(
                    fromFirestore: Profile.fromFirestore,
                    toFirestore: Profile.toFirestore)
                .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
                .get()
                .catchError((e) => (throw e))
                .then((value) {
              _userProfile = value.data();
            });
          } catch (w) {
            CustomNavigator.instance.navigatorKey.currentState!
                .pushNamedAndRemoveUntil("/login", (r) => false);
          }
        }


That do you expect this to do: .catchError((e) => (throw e))? It seems like a noop to me at first glance.

It is a noop in that I would expect that particular use to bubble out the the external try/catch where I have access to the global navigator.  In other attempts I've tried to handle the error inside there, but that also did nothing helpful.
